# What is the best way to implement user login in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am starting a new Rails project and I need to implement a login system that is secure because the application will be dealing with health data.  What is the best way to lock down the app in rails?

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298/best-solution-for-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [restful-authentication](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/authentication-authorization). Seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

OR 
[Authlogic](http://wiki.github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) - Easy Authentication

Comment: Authlogic is what I use as well. Easy to set up and use.