# How to install AuthLogic plugin for rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am following a Ruby on Rails tutorial in a book that uses Acts As Authenticated, but this seems to no longer be supported. I was searching and came across a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298/best-solution-for-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) which recommends a couple of different alternatives for doing user authentication in rails applications. I think [AuthLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) looks like a good choice. I am using Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7.

The AuthLogic readme section states the following:

> ** Please note the latest version is compatible with rails 3 only. Rails 2
>   should use version 2.X.X **

However, when scrolling down to the section about installing as gem or plugin, it only gives the following examples:

> Rails 3:
>
> $ sudo gem install authlogic
>
> Rails 2:
>
> $ sudo gem install authlogic
>   --version=2.1.6
>
> Or install as a plugin:
>
> script/plugin install
>   git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git

I want to install a plugin, rather than the gem, but I need to do it for 2.3.5, not for 3. Can I install the plugin by version in the same way that it shows how to install the gem by version? For example:

> script/plugin install git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git --version=2.3.5

If this is not how it is done, could someone please explain to me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really would reconsider using as a plugin and instead setup bundler in your project. Your Gemfile line would be `gem 'authlogic', '2.1.6'`. If you are concerned about packaging libraries with your project you can `bundle pack` to include your gems with your project.

Anyway, The following plugin install command should work.

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git -r 'tag v2.1.6'
```

Comment: Also, I would recommend using Devise and CanCan for authentication and permissions.

Comment: Okay, well if I were to use Devise with Rails 2.3.5, how would I install that? Would I just add `gem install devise --version=2.3.5` to the Gemfile of my project and then do the rest of the Bundler setup?

Comment: The gemfile line would be `gem 'devise', '1.3.4'`. A quick search returned '[how to install devise on rails 2.3.5?](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/dbb821bf4ca92705?pli=1)'

Comment: Be sure to follow http://gembundler.com/rails23.html to use bundler with Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

- Installing rails 2.3.5

  1. Create the gemset:rvm gemset create rails2
     2.Setting up rvm to use always this gemset:rvm use 1.8.7@rails2 –default
  2. Gem install rails -v 2.3.5